# How to debug print all method arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, debugging

suppose I have:

`def foo(bar, baz)
  puts "Called foo, bar = #{bar}, baz = #{baz}"
  blah_blah
end`

What could I do for a editor macro like this:

`def foo(bar, baz)
  puts "<the answer to this question>"
  blah_blah
end`

And get the same debug result?

Answer (score 2):

There is some meta-info available inside a method:

```
def foo(bar, baz=2)
  p __method__  #=> : foo
  p method(__method__).parameters # => [[:req, :bar], [:opt, :baz]]
end
foo( 1, 2)


def foo(a: "bar",b: )
  p method(__method__).parameters # => [[:keyreq, :b], [:key, :a]]
end
foo(a: 1,b: 2)
```